# "Player has spaceships" database

Tags: sql, database, innodb, one-to-many

I'm pretty new to modeling databases, this is for a browser game.

Basically a player can spend resources to build spaceships. There are, let's say, 3 types of spaceships.

As I understand it's a 1-N relationship, but I'm really confused at how can I save the quantity of each type of spaceship from a specific player.

Right now I have a Player table, a Spaceship table, and Spaceship table contains 3 rows that represents the specific types of spaceships, with their own name, defense etc. Is that ok ?

I know that Spaceship will store Player's id as a foreign key, but I wonder if I just have to use COUNT function to display the quantity for each spaceship, or use an intermediate association like "Player-has-Spaceship" table with quantity attribute. The latter makes more sense to me.

Didn't try to code it blindly, I want a clear concept first.

Comment: `I know that Spaceship will store Player's id as a foreign key` - only if that table contains the instances of spaceships. What you have described as the spaceship table is a mix between a table of possible spaceship types and a table of created spaceship instances.

Comment: I see. I guess it doesn't make sense to have instances when what I need is just quantity per spaceship type. I'm gonna try with an intermediate table.

Comment: Smells like the term "foreign key" is confusing you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE counts (
    player_id ...,
    spaceship_id ...,
    cnt INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(player_id, spaceship_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

UPDATE counts SET
        cnt = cnt + 1;
    WHERE  player_id = ?
      AND  spaceship_id = ?
```

Comment: This is correct (of course) but could use some more explaintion.  This is the heart of a relational DB -- this is "linking table" that defines the relationship between two tables (in this case User Table and Spaceship Table and the count of that relationship.  It could also have more information (how it was created, how much it cost, when it was created etc etc.   any meta information about this relationship can be stored in this table.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I needed. Actually I don't need any other info so that's perfect.